# In unity 2D after applying force to a rigid body how do I make it rotate to face the direction of travel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

new to all this. I've tried following a few examples i've found on here but none seem to work. The best I have right now is

```
 rb.transform.up = rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.normalized;
```

but this makes the rigid body rotate immediately to the new direction of travel. is there a way to make it so it rotates slower rather than jumping in one frame to the new direction of travel?

Any help would be appreciated :)

here is the code ive used to apply the force, if that matters? i got it from a tutorial to apply force based on dragging the mouse

```
public class DragNShoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float power = 10f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    
    
    public Vector2 minPower;
    public Vector2 maxPower;

    public TrajectoryLine tl;

    Camera cam;

    Vector2 force;
    Vector3 startPoint;
    Vector3 endPoint;

    public void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
        tl = GetComponent<TrajectoryLine>();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            startPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            startPoint.z = 15;
            
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector3 currentPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            currentPoint.z = 15;
            tl.RenderLine(startPoint, currentPoint);
        }

       if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            endPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            endPoint.z = 15;

            force = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(startPoint.x - endPoint.x, minPower.x, maxPower.x), Mathf.Clamp(startPoint.y - endPoint.y, minPower.y, maxPower.y));
            rb.AddForce(force * power, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            tl.EndLine();
        }

        
    }

}
```

and here is script for the rotation

```
public class FaceDirectionOfTravel : MonoBehaviour
{
   
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

   

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rb.transform.up = rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.normalized;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have just taken the velocity and applied that to the rotation, I guess this just immediatly changes it to match, but I want it to visibly rotate to match the rotation. I have tried some examples I have seen on here for Slerp but that only seemed to leave it in free rotation.. I must be missing something really obvious so thought I would ask on here. Thanks.

EDIT:
So I've kinda worked out a way to get it to work by creating another object on top of the object i wish to rotate and use Slerp to rotate the object on top to slowly rotate to the same as the original object which has to snap immediatly due to force applied the code is simply

```
public class RotateSprite : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rbOfTarget;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;

  

    private void Start()
    {
       
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        rb.transform.position = rbOfTarget.transform.position;

        rb.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(rb.transform.rotation, rbOfTarget.transform.rotation, 30* Time.deltaTime);
        

    }
}
```

if anyone knows a better solution do let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Is your game in 3D or 2D? you keep saying it's 2D but the tag says it is 3D and if 2D you wouldn't need a Z position. and if it is in 3D you would have to change the rigidbody2D to just rigidbody.

Comment: It's in 2d , sorry am new to this site so may have tagged wrong. I don't see option for just unity, or unity2D , just unity3D

Comment: this is no an answer to the question, should be a comment.